# Entity Framework and Amazon Aurora

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, amazon-aurora

I'm using an application that uses Postgresql on RDS, and I use Entity Framework.

What if I migrate to Amazon Aurora Postgresql, should I have to change my application? Or only the connection string?

Will the provider continue to work?

Will it affect my application? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think, you need to change only connection string. `Aurora Postgresql` is still PostgreSQL.